# AWS Lambda & Cognito - Updating user phone number attribute without sending an SMS

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am working on an iOS app using Amazon Web Services and I am setting up a user data base using the Cognito Userpool. During the sign up process, if a user enters the wrong phone number by mistake and in result isn't receiving a verification code, I am trying to allow them to then enter a new phone number, and update their phone number user attribute. Right now I am using a Lambda function which uses the AdminUpdateUserAttribute function, which is then connected to a APIGateway which allows me to run it from XCode. The function itself works and it successfully updates the phone number attribute.

**Problem**
The problem that I am running into though, is that after the phone number attribute has been updated with the Lambda function, a verification code is automatically sent to the newly updated phone number via SMS. The verification code is weird though because when I use that code to confirm the user, it doesn't work. Meaning that code is invalid for confirmation purposes. But if I use the Resend Confirmation Code function it will then send a valid confirmation code to the newly updated phone number.

**Question**
So I guess the questions I have are:

1. How can I prevent the automatic SMS from sending after I update the user's phone number attribute?
2. Or, is there a way I can use the verification code that is automatically sent as a confirmation code?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: can you remove the old user and create a new one?

Comment: Technically yes, I could use Lambda to delete the user and then sign the user up again. But I feel like that is kind of sloppy though?